# second maximum value in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a regular dictionary like:

```
A = {37:4783, 92:47834, 12:234234,....}
```

I need to return the second maximum value, the third, and so on. I was trying with:

```
max(A, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

but I got this error: TypeError: 'float' object is unsubscriptable

what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: You're doing everything wrong. You have a set of lists, not a dictionary here.

Comment: sorry, that is what happen after days without sleeping well. XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't look like the keys are relevant at all. Therefore, you can just call [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> A = {37:4783, 92:47834, 12:234234}
>>> sorted(A.values(), reverse=True)
[234234, 47834, 4783]
```

Your code

```
max(A, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

fails because iterating over a dictionary will yield its keys. Therefore, you are essentially calling

```
max([37, 92, 12], key=lambda x:x[1])
```

As you can see, the key doesn't make any sense here; `37[1]` will throw an error. If you want to sort the keys by the corresponding values, either sort the dictionary `items` or retrieve the value in the lambda function (or via [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)):

```
>>> [k for k,v in sorted(A.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)]
[12, 37, 92]
>>> sorted(A, key=lambda k: A[k], reverse=True)
[12, 37, 92]
>>> sorted(A, key=A.get, reverse=True)
[12, 37, 92]
```

Note that the latter may be slower since you need to retrieve every key from the dictionary (although dictionary access is [really fast](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#dict) in Python).

Comment: Hi #phihag... actually that is why I didn't do this. After that I need the information of the keys.

Comment: @Alejandro Ammended the answer with two ways to get the keys.

Comment: I think the local approved idiom is to use `key=A.get` instead of `lambda k: A[k]`.

Comment: @DSM Added that, thanks! It's shorter, but probably not that obvious, so I'm keeping both variants.